# <verb> yourself <adjective> (eg: "eat yourself skinny")

Tags: phrase-usage, reflexive-pronouns, imperative-sentences

I ran into such phrases:

1. *eat yourself skinny*
2. *sleep yourself to death*
3. *run yourself thin*

As far as I understood from the context they mean:

1. *eat until you become skinny*
2. *sleep until you die*
3. *run until you become thin*

Am I right?

Can I translate ***any*** phrase "*do something until you become **adjective***" into phrase "*do something yourself **adjective***"?

Are there any situations when I have to use *herself*, *himself* etc instead of *yourself*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the pattern

> *verb* until you become *adjective*

into

> *verb* something yourself *adjective*

in most circumstances

> *laugh* yourself *silly*
>   *run* yourself *ragged*
>   *eat* yourself *fat*
>   *study* yourself *smart*

You would use

> himself
>   herself
>   themselves

to refer to a third person in the same way you would use "he" and "she"

> she laughed **herself** silly
>   he ran **himself** ragged
>   They ate **themselves** fat

Comment: It's usually *other people* who run you ragged, and I have to say both OP's *eat oneself skinny* and your *eat oneself fat* sound a bit weird to me. I'm more used to, for example, ***worried himself sick, laughed himself hoarse, shook himself awake*.

Comment: "Don't run yourself ragged!" is a standard phrase to mean "Take care of yourself, don't do too many things at once!". "Eat yourself skinny." is a phrase used by people who advocate eating "negative" calorie foods like celery. "Eat yourself fat" is, well, just eating too much. Your other examples are very good.

Answer (score 1):

1) It also very much means that the adjective is caused by the verb, and in a forceful way.

2) You *can* replace the words with other ones of your choosing, BUT unless the new phrases are familiar and traditional, they can sound strange.  It's safer to stick to phrases that you've seen already.  In every example I can think of, the phrase is "correct" just because we are used to hearing it.